# Are there any "joint-categorical" structures that have been considered in the literature? What should one call such a structure?

Tags: reference-request, category-theory

Suppose we have some collection of objects $\mathrm{Ob}(\mathcal{C})$, and for all $A,B \in \mathrm{Ob}(\mathcal{C})$ a collection of morphisms $\mathrm{Hom}(A,B)$ together with two, for all objects $A,B,C$ functions: $\circ, \bullet : \mathrm{Hom}(C,B) \times \mathrm{Hom}(A,B) \to \mathrm{Hom}(A,C)$ such that $(\mathcal{C},\circ)$ and $(\mathcal{C},\bullet)$ (with appropriate identity morphisms) both form categories, and satisfy some sort of compatibility condition(s). For instance:

$$f \circ (g \bullet h) = (f \circ g) \bullet h$$

Has this sort of structure been considered before? What are (or should!) such "joint-categorical" structures be called?

Note that what I am looking for here is very different on the surface from the structure of an $n$-category, but perhaps one might be able to describe this structure $n$-categorically.

Comment: Do you have an example in mind which doesn't involve $\circ = \bullet$?

Comment: I believe any double category should satisfy this, right? In a double category, one asks that $(a \bullet b) \circ (c \bullet d) = (a \circ c) \bullet (b \circ d)$. So if $b$ is the identity, then we get $a \circ (c \bullet d) = (a \circ c) \bullet d$.

Comment: @Mr.Chip Sure, take any algebraic structure with two binary operations, both of which have identities (e.x. a ring with unity, or a lattice), then such a structure can be considered as such a "double category" with a single object.

Comment: @NathanBeDell Your examples do not satisfy the composition rule you mentioned : for rings, in general $x+yz\neq (x+y)z$, and for lattices in general $x\wedge (y\vee z)\neq (x\wedge y)\vee z$.

Comment: @ArnaudD. Right, of course. The example I had in mind when I wrote that was modular lattices, but now that I think of it, what I wrote won't even hold in general there. The specific law isn't important though. It could be any equational law relating $\bullet$ and $\circ$. I suppose the difficult point is ensuring the compositions remain well-defined on both sides of the equality.